# ASP MVC table foreign key configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class Movies
{
    [Key]
    public int movieID { get; set; }

    public String Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Genres parentGenre { get; set; }
}


public class Genres
{
    public Genres()
    {
        this.movies = new HashSet<Movies>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int genreId { get; set; }

    public String genreName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Movies> movies { get; set; }
}
```

I can successfully create a DropDownList on my addmovie view page by reading in the Genres table.

But when I try submit the page, it states "The value '10' is invalid." This leads me to believe that I am trying to put an Int (from the dropdownlist value) into an object (from the "Genres parentGenre").

Have I set up the "Genres parentGenre" to "genreId" foreign key relationship correctly to where it should only want a 'number' for the "parentGenre" field, or does it expect more?

added:

controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Movies movies)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movies);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Genres
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.genreId).Trim(),
                                Text = c.genreName
                            });
        ViewBag.genreId = items;
    }
```

view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parentGenre.genreName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.parentGenre,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.genreId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parentGenre)
```

Comment: How are you posting values? Can you add some more of the controller / view code so we can get a better idea on what's going on?

Comment: In your DropDownListFor, have you tried using model.parentGenre.genreId? I believe with MVC modelbinding, you actually have to use the property, or else it won't know what to bind it to. Right now, it's trying to bind an integer to a complex object and without altering the model binder, it can't make that leap.

Comment: I'm reading the material I was shown,  I'm now trying to understand why the object would even need to be complex, considering I'm reading from 2 tables, but only writing to 1 (or at least that's how db's use to be)

Comment: Is movie -> genre one to one, or one to many?

Comment: ha! i was just thinking about that.  one to one....the genre is only for lookup

Comment: Edited my answer - though it may not be 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of your comments, here's what I'd recommend:

Models:

```
public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int MovieID { get; set; }

        public String Title { get; set; }

        public int GenreId { get; set; }

        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public Genre()
    {
        this.movies = new HashSet<Movies>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Movie Movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Movies.Add(Movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Genres
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.GenreId).Trim(),
                            Text = c.Name
                        });
    ViewBag.genreId = items;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre.Id,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.genreId)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
</div>
```

If I'm *reading* what you're doing correctly, that should work. I haven't done much with EF though, so I can't be 100% certain.

Comment: now it says "A genre name is required" which goes with the Genre.genreName errormessage.. I'm currently reading the binding pages, was requested

Comment: to me, your post (the newb, I am) says to write to the Genre table, do I really need to do that? I thought the Genre table was just for look ups.

Comment: Edited to reflect our discussion - interested if this ended up helping, just let me know!

Comment: Shouldn't public ICollection<Movies> Movies be virtual as well?